# Use query result from many to many relations to sort list in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

Here's what my Admin class looks like

```
class GuestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (GuestEpisodeAdmin, TopicGuestAdmin, JobGuestAdmin)
    exclude = ('episodes', )
    list_display = ('name', 'twitter', 'gender', 'medium', 'appearance_count', 'last_appearance')
    list_filter = ['gender']
    search_fields = ['name', 'twitter', 'bio', 'notes']

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(GuestAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        qs = qs.annotate(
            _appearance_count=Count('episodes')
        )
        return qs

    def appearance_count(self, obj):
        return obj._appearance_count

    def last_appearance(self, obj):
        la = obj.episodes.order_by('-published_at').values_list('published_at', flat=True).all().first()
        if isinstance(la, datetime.datetime):
            la = la.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        return la

    # last_appearance.admin_order_field = 'last_appearance'
    appearance_count.admin_order_field = '_appearance_count'
```

So the last_appearance comes from the episodes connected to the guest (many-to-many relationship) by using the publish date from the newest episode. My goal is to have them sortable in the list view on django admin.

I learned that I can't get this into the `get_queryset`but i'm sure there is a way. I couldn't find one yet.

Comment: why can't you `annotate(_last_appearance=Max('episodes__published_at'))`?

Comment: @dirkgroten because this is exactly was I was missing as a syntax. Thanks! Care to post this as a proper answer so I can mark it as the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Max` function to annotate your `queryset`, which also works on `DateTimeField`s, so you actually can implement this in the `get_queryset()` method:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(GuestAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    qs = qs.annotate(
        _appearance_count=Count('episodes'),
        _last_appearance=Max('episodes__published_at')
    )
    return qs

...
last_appearance.admin_order_field = '_last_appearance'
```